FInding global min cut in undirected graph using N -1 max flows
I am trying to implement a algorithm to find the global min cut in a weighted undirected graph with N nodes using max flow. The general idea is to fix a source node and apply a max flow algorithm (like Dinic's) from this source node to every other one of the remaining N - 1 nodes.
I tried to implement the algorihtm exactly this way and, despite working, the implementation is way to slow. In particular, I noticed the bottleneck of the implementation is reseting the edges capacities after every run of the max flow algorithm. I don't how to optimize that neither if it is possible to do so. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can use the Stoer-Wagner algorithm to find the global min cut instead of finding the min s-t cut for every possible value of t.
